# How to intercept and manipulate a Internet Explorer popup with VBA

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, dom, automation, popup

**Language/Software:**

The language is VBA. The application is Access 2003 (I also can use Excel) and Internet Explorer (on Windows XP/Seven).

**The problem:**

I'm  developing a Access macro which opens and manipulates a intranet site of the enterprise where I work.

I can create new IE windows and fill data in the forms, but I need to be able of intercept and manipulate other IE windows, such as popups, which opens when I click on a link, when I choose an option of a select element or when the page is loaded.

Comment: Is the popup modal? Can you continue to manipulate background pages when the popup is open?

Comment: No. After the pop ups are open I can still handle the pages that generates the popups.

Comment: What type of pop ups and what do you want to do with them? Eg do you mean when you login a new window opens?

Comment: For example, the kind generated with this javascript function: 'function popup(mylink, windowname) { if (! window.focus)return true; var href; if (typeof(mylink) == 'string') href=mylink; else href=mylink.href; window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes'); return false; }'. My aim is to fill some forms necessary to send some requisitions of data to other sector in the enterprise. This requisitions are very important and I prefer to avoid typing manually to avoid errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some code I use to get an IE window from it's title. It's split into two functions because one of my users was having an extremely odd problem where an error was not being caught properly. You might (probably will) be able to move the body of the private function into the public function.

Additionally, you'll need to set a reference to Microsoft Internet Controls (this is either shdocvw.dll or ieframe.dll, depending on your version of Windows) and I'd recommend setting a reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library to make it easier to traverse the DOM once you have your IE object.

```
Function oGetIEWindowFromTitle(sTitle As String, _
                               Optional bCaseSensitive As Boolean = False, _
                               Optional bExact As Boolean = False) As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Dim objShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim startTime As Single

    found = False
    'Loop through shell windows
    For Each oGetIEWindowFromTitle In objShellWindows
        found = oGetIEWindowFromTitleHandler(oGetIEWindowFromTitle, sTitle, bCaseSensitive, bExact)
        If found Then Exit For
    Next

    'Check whether a window was found
    If Not found Then
        Set oGetIEWindowFromTitle = Nothing
    Else
        pauseUntilIEReady oGetIEWindowFromTitle
    End If

End Function

Private Function oGetIEWindowFromTitleHandler(win As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, _
                                      sTitle As String, _
                                      bCaseSensitive As Boolean, _
                                      bExact As Boolean) As Boolean

    oGetIEWindowFromTitleHandler = False

    On Error GoTo handler
    'If the document is of type HTMLDocument, it is an IE window
    If TypeName(win.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
        'Check whether the title contains the passed title
        If bExact Then
            If (win.Document.title = sTitle) Or ((Not bCaseSensitive) And (LCase(sTitle) = LCase(win.Document.title))) Then oGetIEWindowFromTitleHandler = True
        Else
            If InStr(1, win.Document.title, sTitle) Or ((Not bCaseSensitive) And (InStr(1, LCase(win.Document.title), LCase(sTitle), vbTextCompare) <> 0)) Then oGetIEWindowFromTitleHandler = True
        End If
    End If
handler:
    'We assume here that if an error is raised it's because
    'the window is not of the correct type. Therefore we
    'simply ignore it and carry on.

End Function
```

Use the above code as follows:

```
Sub test()

    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument 'If you have a reference to the HTML Object Library
    'Dim doc as Object 'If you do not have a reference to the HTML Object Library

    ' Change the title here as required
    Set ie = oGetIEWindowFromTitle("My popup window")
    Set doc = ie.Document

    Debug.Print doc.getElementsByTagName("body").Item(0).innerText

End Sub
```

You can find a window from almost any property of the window, or it's document contents. If you're struggling with this, please comment :).

Comment: My only doubt is about "pauseUntilIEReady", but I suppose that it must be a Sub with a Do While IE.Busy... Anyway its already working.

Comment: @NathanNathan ah, it's a little more than that because I have an odd use case, but that's all you should need in most cases. Sorry for not noticing it was still there! Happy to help :)

Comment: Great answer, and nice coding.  I needed to be able to ID a window on its URL, and it was very easy to swap the win.Document.[property] to the url property.

Comment: Thank you, happy to have helped!

Comment: yeah this is really great, +1 vote. Not a lot of information on VBA automation when multiple IEs are open

Comment: So what should go in the place of `pauseUntilIEReady oGetIEWindowFromTitle` because it's throwing an error for me?

Comment: @MattCremeens, I'm not sure I can help you. I haven't written any VBA in years and have no way to test any suggestions I make (no Windows machines around). That said, Nathan above suggests that you might be able to replace that line with something like `Do While oGetIEWindowFromTitle.Busy` in order to block code execution until the window is available for manipulation. You could also try to take that line out and see if that works for you.

Comment: @mkingston thank you. In the end, I was able to work something out for my situation.