# Get IE window object by window title with VBA

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, automation

I found this solution provided by @mkingston:
[How to intercept and manipulate a Internet Explorer popup with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446951/solved-how-to-intercept-and-manipulate-a-internet-explorer-popup-with-vba)

...but it's not working for me. I've added both of the reference libraries in question, but when I run the script I run into these issues:

Compile error: Undefined Sub due to pauseUntilIEReady (since this Sub wasn't included with the answer, I remove it from the script)

Compile error: Argument not optional due to oGetIEWindowFromTitle (so I tried commeting this out to get the script to compile)

After the script finally compiles, it get this error:

Automation error
The system cannot find the file specified.

on this line of code:
For Each oGetIEWindowFromTitle In objShellWindows

Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
Function oGetIEWindowFromTitle(sTitle As String, _
                           Optional bCaseSensitive As Boolean = False, _
                           Optional bExact As Boolean = False) As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Dim objShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
Dim found As Boolean
Dim startTime As Single

found = False
'Loop through shell windows
For Each oGetIEWindowFromTitle In objShellWindows
    found = oGetIEWindowFromTitleHandler(oGetIEWindowFromTitle, sTitle, bCaseSensitive, bExact)
    If found Then Exit For
Next

'Check whether a window was found
If Not found Then
    Set oGetIEWindowFromTitle = Nothing
Else
    'COMMENTED OUT TO GET SCRIPT TO COMPILE pauseUntilIEReady oGetIEWindowFromTitle
End If

End Function


Private Function oGetIEWindowFromTitleHandler(win As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, _
                                  sTitle As String, _
                                  bCaseSensitive As Boolean, _
                                  bExact As Boolean) As Boolean

oGetIEWindowFromTitleHandler = False

On Error GoTo handler
'If the document is of type HTMLDocument, it is an IE window
If TypeName(win.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
    'Check whether the title contains the passed title
    If bExact Then
        If (win.Document.title = sTitle) Or ((Not bCaseSensitive) And (LCase(sTitle) = LCase(win.Document.title))) Then oGetIEWindowFromTitleHandler = True
    Else
        If InStr(1, win.Document.title, sTitle) Or ((Not bCaseSensitive) And (InStr(1, LCase(win.Document.title), LCase(sTitle), vbTextCompare) <> 0)) Then oGetIEWindowFromTitleHandler = True
    End If
End If
handler:
'We assume here that if an error is raised it's because
'the window is not of the correct type. Therefore we
'simply ignore it and carry on.

End Function
```

and

```
Sub test()

Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument 'If you have a reference to the HTML Object Library
'Dim doc as Object 'If you do not have a reference to the HTML Object Library

' Change the title here as required
Set ie = oGetIEWindowFromTitle("My popup window")
Set doc = ie.Document

Debug.Print doc.getElementsByTagName("body").Item(0).innerText

End Sub
```

Comment: Post the actual code you're trying to use.

Comment: Hi Tim, I didn't post the code initially because it's the same proposed in the linked solution. I've copied it below with the one line commented out that I had to comment to get the code to compile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works for me.

```
Function IEWindowFromTitle(sTitle As String) As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Dim objShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
    Dim win As Object, rv As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    For Each win In objShellWindows
        If TypeName(win.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
            If UCase(win.Document.Title) = UCase(sTitle) Then
                Set rv = win
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set IEWindowFromTitle = rv

End Function

Sub Tester()

    Dim w As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set w = IEWindowFromTitle("Google")
    If Not w Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print w.Document.Title
    Else
        Debug.Print "Not found"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim. When I run that I get: "Automation error / The system cannot find the file specified" with VBA breaking at this line: "For Each win In objShellWindows"

Comment: Works fine for me.  32-bit Excel on Win7 64-bit.

Comment: Trying from installs of Excel 2010 on two different computers both running Win7. What reference libraries might I need other than Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library?

Comment: Ok, I modified the script to include `For Each win In objShellWindows /
        MsgBox (win.Name) /
    Next` which returns "Windows Internet Explorer" (and using LocationURL returns the url) but win.Document or win.Document.Name fails because it says Document isn't a valid property or method.

Comment: You need to reference `Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation`

Comment: That works for one of my versions of Excel. Unfortunately the other computer I actually need to run the script on still gives me "Automation error / The system cannot find the file specified" at the "For Each win In objShellWindows" line. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: When testing this code in Visual Studio 2013 with IE11, `TypeName(win.Document) = "HTMLDocument"` had to be changed to `TypeName(win.Document) = "HTMLDocumentClass"`.

Comment: This is VBA, not VB.NET

Comment: Sure, but most of the code works anyway. I figured if I happened across this article when trying to find a solution, others might and that little piece of information might prove useful.