# vba html click not working

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

I am getting URLs from charts that are generated from a web page.  It loops through stocks, and then creates the charts.  I have the whole process automated except for one button.

On the first stock, my code works great, but it doesn't work after that.

Here is the HTML...

```
<tr data-menuitem="save" style="border: 1px solid rgb(174, 185, 197); height: 32px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; font-size: 11px; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial; background-color: rgba(179, 213, 253, 0);">
<td valign="middle" align="center" title="Save Chart" style="cursor: default; border: none;">  <img width="24" height="24" class="icon" style="display:block" src="/chartnotes/img/unsaved.gif">
</td>
</tr>
```

And here is my vba trying to click the button...

```
        Set IEDoc = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("td")
        If IEDoc(258).getAttribute("Title") = "Save Chart" Then
            IEDoc(258).Click
        ElseIf IEDoc(114).getAttribute("Title") = "Save Chart" Then
            IEDoc(114).Click
        Else
            Stop
        End If
```

I am sure that it is finding the correct element, because it runs the code for IEDoc(258).Click each time.  But the actual action of the button only happens on the first pass.

Thoughts?

Comment: There is no button in the HTML. The element you call click for is a table cell. You could simplify the code by using `querySelector` or by using `Function querySelectorAll(v As String) As IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection`. Example: `IE.Document.querySelector("td[title='Save Chart']")`.

Comment: Nice!  In my young HTML automation career, I've not used querySelector.  I just replaced most of my code with your suggested IE.Document.querySelector("td[title='Save Chart']").

Comment: Nice!  In my young HTML automation career, I've not used querySelector.  I just replaced most of my code with your suggested IE.Document.querySelector("td[title='Save Chart']").

It worked, but again, just on the first pass.  It didn't actually perform the action on any of the subsequent passes.

Comment: Yes `queryString` is very useful! I learned it here on SO as well. To be honest I don't know what is wrong with the next `Clicks`. What does the first `Click` do? Is there some `java-script` attached to `onclick` event of the `td` elements? Maybe the java-script changes something and so the next clicks don't work the same way?

Comment: How would I find out whether there is java-script involved?

Comment: I hate it that I keep hitting enter, before I'm done typing.  :(  The first click (that works) opens another window, and that window has buttons with IDs that are easy to control.

Comment: [Use F12 in IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589512(v=vs.85).aspx). Then go to `scripts` tab and try to find some script which could be atached to that `click`.

Comment: Hmm another window opens? Thats is maybe the problem because you are referencing elements in the previous window, but buttons are in another window. Probably you would need something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664845/get-ie-window-object-by-window-title-with-vba) or [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/596c22cb-2140-404c-87b1-b115ecf1da03/controlling-open-internet-explorer-windows-with-vba?forum=isvvba). Then when you have reference to the active IE use Document of it.

Comment: So, here is what I found from your suggestions... (1) No Java-script associated with that one.  (2) The onclick event should open another window, but the other window does not have it's own URL (at least not visible).  And... the buttons on the window that opens are easily controlled, so once it opens, I'm Golden.  I just need it to open every time.  Any other thoughts?  And... many thanks for your help in this.

Comment: You are welcome! But I am little confused. Could you add some screen shots or video where the situation with the another window(s) will be shown?

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I don't feel comfortable posting pics or video of this process on the web.  It's not my data.

Comment: Darn Enter Key Again!!!   The Save Data "button" (actually table cell) is just a button that says Save Data when you hover it.  When you click it, a small window opens (that does not have its own URL), and it has two buttons (Upload and Cancel).  I have been able to click these buttons without difficulty.  The problem is just clicking that Save Chart button (or should I say... Having it respond to my click).