# Copy content of the last popup window

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to open IE, login with username/password, tick some checkboxes, click button and open a report on a pop up window.

I am trying to copy the content of the pop up window to an Excel sheet. The code that deals with the pop up window doesn't detect the url.

```
Sub MyRosterApps()
Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument

Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer, t As Date, nodeList As Object, i As Long
Dim ieIEWindow As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim y As Integer
Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5

'Ignore Errors
On Error GoTo Err_Clear
MyURL = "Not a public URL"

Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True
Do
    'Wait till finished
Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set HTMLdoc = MyBrowser.document

'Enter user / password
HTMLdoc.all.txtUsername.Value = "username" ' Eneter your email id here
HTMLdoc.all.txtPassword.Value = "password" 'Enter your password here
HTMLdoc.all.Item("btnLogin").Click

For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLdoc.getElementsByName("btnLogin")
    If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

Do
    'Wait till finished
Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLdoc = MyBrowser.document

HTMLdoc.all.Item("ucSkillsPicker_lstSkills_35").Click
HTMLdoc.all.Item("btnShowReport").Click

' The Pop Up windows opens
Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLdoc = MyBrowser.document

' Until here is works fine

' Trying to deal with the Pop Up windows
With objIE
    .Visible = True

    ' I am trying to get the active window url which is the pop up

    .navigate ieIEWindow.LocationURL

    Do While .Busy = True Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    t = Timer
    Do
        DoEvents
        On Error Resume Next

        ' Go thru DIV classes and find  these two oReportCell .a71

        Set nodeList = .document.querySelectorAll("#oReportCell .a71")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do

    Loop While nodeList Is Nothing

    If Not nodeList Is Nothing Then

        'Paste the value found in DIV classes in Sheet1

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
                .Cells(1, i + 1) = nodeList.Item(i).innerText
            Next
        End With
    End If
    .Quit
End With             

Err_Clear:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        'Debug.Assert Err = 0
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
    End If

End Sub
```

This code below is separate from above. If I run just like this it does what I need. Of course, I have to paste the targeted window url.

```
.navigate "url of the pop up window"
```

The issue is that the pop up window url expires or something like that.
After some time the page says that I have to go through selecting some check boxes and submit.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GrabLastNames()
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer, t As Date, nodeList As Object, i As Long
Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

With objIE
    .Visible = True
    ' Paste targeted window. In my case is the pop up window
    .navigate "url of the pop up window"

    Do While .Busy = True Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    t = Timer
    Do
        DoEvents
        On Error Resume Next
        Set nodeList = .document.querySelectorAll("#oReportCell .a71")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do

    Loop While nodeList Is Nothing

    If Not nodeList Is Nothing Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
            For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
                .Cells(1, i + 1) = nodeList.item(i).innerText
            Next
        End With
    End If
    .Quit
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So Set nodeList = .document.querySelectorAll("#oReportCell .a71") is where you want to grab information right? What does nodeList evaluate to here?

Comment: So what is the real problem here? That you can't combine login and accessing info from the pop-up window? If that is the case you may need to [loop IE windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664845/get-ie-window-object-by-window-title-with-vba) to find the one with .URL = to the one you are interested in or has the caption you are after and then work with that. You can also use API calls to FindWindow but that is a little more complex.

Comment: @siggi_pop that's right. nodeList gets value insdie DIV Classes oReportCell .a71"

Comment: @Harr I can't get     .navigate ieIEWindow.LocationURL to read the last opened browser

Comment: You use `.Navigate2` these days.

Comment: ^^ Good point. I often forget that!

Comment: What do you mean by read? Are you getting the right window firstly? And I suspect you need to use the window/document title rather than the URL (my bad for earlier comment as if you knew the URL in advance you would simply use that.... or have you and it isn't working?) and then grab the URL from that window to use in your navigate2.

Comment: @QHarr I have updated my question. Hope it's clear now

Comment: How does your above code fit together? You have a Do without a Loop by the looks of it. Are you finding the new window?

Comment: @QHarr those two codes are separate. The second one works fine. You see that I tried to combine those two together, but doesn't work. It opens the window (pop up) but it doesn't get the values. I tried to pate some stuff from the first window and it pasted the values. So, it's still not getting the pop up window. Also, the pop up window takes about couple second to pop.

Comment: What I am saying is that you need to find the popup window with code otherwise it is likely you are still working with the original document from the opening URL. There is nothing in your code that helps you get that new window e.g. looping windows using Shell or API calls with FindWindow or UI Automation.