# Invalid Procedure Call or Argument - Shell Object

Tags: vba, automation, explorer

I am trying to use a macro to detect an internet explorer window that has opened, but every time I run the following code:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    IE_Count = objShell.Windows.Count
    For x = 0 To (IE_Count - 1)
       ' On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
        my_title = objShell.Windows(x).document.Title
        If my_title = target Then 'compare to find if the desired web page is already open
            Set IE = objShell.Windows(x)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

I receive the error,

> Run-time error '5': Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

When I debug the program, it points to this line:

```
my_title = objShell.Windows(x).document.Title
```

After some playing around, I have discovered that the "x" variable is causing the error, and I'm not sure why. If I replace the x with an actual integer (i.e. 0 or 1), it works perfectly fine. Am I not allowed to use variables to store integers with shell objects? I could really use a point in the right direction here.

Comment: `Windows` also includes any open Windows Explorer objects, and those don't have a `Document` property

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56758969/how-to-get-the-title-of-a-website-page-in-vba

Comment: oops... didn't see your comment. Anyways found a post by you @TimWilliams :D

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you! That is all I needed to know.