# VBA Excel Macro Stops Working When a Dialog Box Pop Up Appears - InternetExplorer.Application

Tags: vba, excel

I was automating a client website using macros, I was able to automate all the fields but I face this pop up during the execution:

[image: popup Image]

Because of this pop up, macros execution wont proceed further
it gets stuck there and i have to manually click OK to proceed with further.

i tried to follow this video in YouTube 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-2khNFYQl8

but our company blocks all vbs scripts, so i wanted to know any other soln for this pop up issue

The code sample :

```
if (g_form.getValue('comments') == '') {
    //Remove any existing field message, set comments mandatory, and show a new field message
    try {g_form.hideFieldMsg('comments');} catch(e) {}
    g_form.setMandatory('comments', true);
    g_form.showFieldMsg('comments','Comments are required when resolving an Incident.','error');
    alert('Click the Resolve Incident button again, the Save button, or the Update button after entering all mandatory Resolution fields.');
    return false;  //Abort submission
}
//Call the UI Action and skip the 'onclick' function
gsftSubmit(null, g_form.getFormElement(), 'resolve_incident'); //MUST call the 'Action name' set in this UI Action
```

So can anyone help me regarding this issue
thanking you in advances

Comment: You should be able to "unhook" the alert to prevent it showing, but you don't show any of the page source, so it's difficult to provide any useful guidance here....

Comment: Hi Tim , thank you for the update ,

Comment: can you please tel me about the "unhook"

Comment: regarding the page source , the website is confendial , so page source cannot be uploaded

Comment: they have a alert in the code , for this pop up

Comment: alert('Click the Resolve Incident button again, the Save button, or the Update button after entering all mandatory Resolution fields.');
  return false;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to intercept and manipulate a Internet Explorer popup with VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446951/how-to-intercept-and-manipulate-a-internet-explorer-popup-with-vba)

Comment: Hi Robin , the above solution i tired before and it was not working , issue i was facing was the macro wont proceed further , it gets stuck the moment the pop up comes and i have to manually click on OK to proceed further

Comment: That's too little code to make any difference to your question being answerable: you don't need to provide the whole page, just the part which shows exactly how the alert is triggered.

Comment: You can execute this snippet of javascript in the page once it has loaded `window.alert = function() {};`  That will/should overwrite the regular `alert()` function and stop it from showing a messagebox.

Comment: if (g_form.getValue('comments') == '') {
  //Remove any existing field message, set comments mandatory, and show a new field message
  try {g_form.hideFieldMsg('comments');} catch(e) {}
  g_form.setMandatory('comments', true);
  g_form.showFieldMsg('comments','Comments are required when resolving an Incident.','error');
  alert('Click the Resolve Incident button again, the Save button, or the Update button after entering all mandatory Resolution fields.');
  return false;  //Abort submission
 }
 gsftSubmit(null, g_form.getFormElement(), 'resolve_incident');

Comment: i have added the code in the description , please refer it