# How do I use an IE session after intercepting it with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer

I apologise that this has been covered before in previous posts but I feel they may be a bit out of date as the current iterations of VB.Net do not use the Set option anymore.

I have been trying to work around this to figure it out but have been really struggling.

My problem: I have a application I am building to automate some tedious tasks. This involves multiple IE sessions which I have working in their own webbrowser controls. One of them however I get to a point then it wants to launch a popup in a new Internet explorer window. I have been toying with using the newwindow event to try and play with it but have had no success.

Below is the code I am trying to use to capture the popup window:

```
Shared Function IEWindowFromTitle(sTitle As String) As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Dim objShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
    Dim win As Object, rv As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    For Each win In objShellWindows
        If TypeName(win.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
            If UCase(win.Document.Title) = UCase(sTitle) Then
                rv = win
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    IEWindowFromTitle = rv

End Function
```

I am trying to call it with:

```
    Shared Sub thissubmakesmeasadpanda()

    Dim w As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    w = IEWindowFromTitle("Address Search")
    If Not w Is Nothing Then
        Debug.WriteLine(w.Document.Title)
    Else
        Debug.WriteLine("Not found")
    End If

End Sub
```

I seem to be getting an error when I run this though the error being:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80004005 (E_FAIL))

I am at a bit of a loss at this point after trying to follow a number of different posts on here most recently [How to intercept and manipulate a Internet Explorer popup with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446951/how-to-intercept-and-manipulate-a-internet-explorer-popup-with-vba) 
and 
[Get IE window object by window title with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664845/get-ie-window-object-by-window-title-with-vba)

There are a few tasks that will need to be completed at the end of this such as filling information into a text box and then clicking a search button, and clicking a result.

when you click the result however it comes up with a confirmation box which is not an ie window I would describe it more like being a msgbox type element that asks to confirm importing the details. Once you click ok the actions taken in the popup window then are meant to download into the webcontrol that launched the new browser. 
Please note I have built the application up until this point and when I manually do the tasks it works. I tried using the newwindow event to open a new form with a browser and navigate it to the target URL however when I manually filled the text boxes and did the clicks nothing was sent back to the original webbrowser control.

Any help is greatly appreciated. The website I am trying to work with is an internal one so not something I can freely share.