# How do i click on allow pop-ups diologue box, save as diologue box in Internet explorer using VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, popup, explorer

How do I allow my website to go through pop ups using vba in IE. Also I am trying to do save as for documents in IE using VBA. Can some body please help?

I need some thing like

if window like allow popups - allow
file open, save - save as

Answer (score 0):

We usually use the below code to open a url in IE, you can use this to open your website:

```
Sub LOADIE()
    Set ieA = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ieA.Visible = True
    ieA.navigate "WWW.XXXX.COM"
    Do Until ieA.readyState = 4
       DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

For further information, you can also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446951/how-to-intercept-and-manipulate-a-internet-explorer-popup-with-vba). And about save files you can refer to [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bd0ee306-7bb5-4ce4-8341-edd9475f84ad/excel-2007-use-vba-to-download-amp-save-csv-from-url?forum=isvvba).