# Send login details from VBA to HTML popup window

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

Is it possible to send login details from VBA to a HTML popup window? I invoke the main HTML page easily enough, but then a popup login window appears & my code returns an error "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable". :

```
Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
With appIE
    .navigate sURL
    .Visible = True
End With
Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop
' ERROR OCCURS HERE - "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable"
Set objCollection = appIE.document.getElementById("inputUsername")
objCollection.Value = "xxxxx.xxxx@xxx.xxx.xx"
Set objCollection2 = appIE.document.getElementById("inputPassword")
objCollection2.Value = "yyyyyy"
```

Popup HTML is (I've cut out some lines):

```html
<div class="input-prepend">
  <label class="add-on " for="inputPassword" data-ng-class="{'text-error': passwordRequired}">Password</label>
  <input name="inputPassword" class="input-medium ng-pristine ng-valid" id="inputPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" data-ng-model="password">
</div>
```

Comment: Somewhat little information. Is it an intranet or internet URL? Can you post the url or for what reasons is it not reachable for other ones if it is an internet url? What kind of pop up? An own IE window or something else? Please post at least your whole VBA code because I cannot see where a pop-up pops up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to intercept and manipulate a Internet Explorer popup with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446951/how-to-intercept-and-manipulate-a-internet-explorer-popup-with-vba)